# I have developed an application that is working on the api17 but it was unable to work on api 8 but I have given the minimum sdk as 8

Tags: android

In api 17 it is working but when I installed the application in the gingerbread version of android 2.3 version it was showing unfortunately stopped application.

Comment: What was the error? Can you post your logcat?

Comment: Maybe you call functions which is available only in API 17. Show your LogCat.

Comment: i have added action bar in my application

Comment: My logcat Shows this error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.nst.fabrics.MainActivity.getActionBar

Comment: getActionBar doesn't exist in Android 2.3. Use ActionBar from support library. Link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In project structure choose android api 8 and you will see what android features you used that do not support android 8.

To Ciril:

[ListView supports from api 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html)

Answer (score 0):

It may cause by two reasons,

1) If you try to use the higher version features like listView, Tabbed layout etc. The listView support only in api level 11 or higher.

2) If you don't have the proper support libraries in your project. To solve this error Right click on the project -> Select Android Tools -> Add Support Library.

Then Eclipse will find the proper library, if it is the reason for the error.

Comment: @Ervin: Thanks bro. Actually one of my application cause a Fatal exception that shows the error related to the api level and listView, and it solved by adding the support library. Thats why I mentioned relations between api level and listView but thats not correct listView supports from API level 1 !!!

Answer (score 0):

For the action bar you could use sherlock actionbar for android api levels below 11

Comment: do u have any example

Comment: Please refer to this: 
http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html and http://www.grokkingandroid.com/adding-actionbarsherlock-to-your-project/